# How to rewrite a Java recursive service to .Net 5?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, .net-5

I have Java service what creates Menu tree with all children. It works perfectly for Menu.
I want to rewrite with .Net5 but it's difficult for me.

```
// Java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public  class AdminNode implements Iterable<Resource>
{
    private Resource   resource;
    private List<AdminNode> children;
    
    
    public List<AdminNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    
    public AdminNode(Resource resource)
    {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    
    public void addResource(Resource resource)
    {
        String[] pathArr = resource.getPath().split("-");

        List<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++) {
            intArray.add(Integer.parseInt(pathArr[i]));
        }
          
        addResource(resource, intArray);   
    }
    

    private void addResource(Resource resource,  List<Integer> path)
    {
        if (path.size() > 1)
        { 
            Integer nextParent =  path.get(0);
            path.remove(0);
         
            for (AdminNode child : children)
            {
                if (child.getResource().getId().equals(nextParent))
                {
                    child.addResource(resource, path);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            children.add(new AdminNode(resource));
        }
    }

    public Resource getResource() { return resource; }
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<Resource> iterator()
    {
        return  stream().iterator();
    }
    
    public Stream<Resource> stream()
    {
        return goDown(this).skip(1).map(AdminNode::getResource);
    }
    
    private static Stream<AdminNode> goDown(AdminNode node)
    { 
        Stream<AdminNode> result = Stream.concat(Stream.of(node), node.children.stream().flatMap(AdminNode::goDown));
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AdminNode [resource=" + resource + ", children=" + children + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

I think class can to be:

```
// C#
public class AdminNode : IEnumerable<Resource> {
   private Resource _resource;
   private List<AdminNode> _children;

  public List<AdminNode> getChildren() {
        return _children;
    }

  public AdminNode(Resource resource)
    {
        _resource = resource;
        _children = new List<>();
    }

  public void addResource(Resource resource)
    {
        var pathArr = _resource.Path.Split("-");
         var intArray = new List<int>();       

        for(int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length; i++) {
            intArray.Add(Convert.ToInt32(pathArr[i]));
        }

        addResource(resource, intArray);   
    }

   private void AddResource(Resource resource, List<int> path)
        {
            if (path.Count > 1)
            {
                var nextParent = path[0];
                path.Remove(0);

                foreach (void child in _children)
                {
                    if (child.GetResource().Id == nextParent)
                    {
                        child.AddResource(resource, path);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _children.Add(new AdminNode(resource));
            }
        }

     public Resource GetResource() { return _resource; }
     

      public IEnumerator<Resource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            //?
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            // ?
        }

    // and there I stopped.
}
```

.Net5 does not has Stream, flatMap. Maybe FlatMap I can change with Linq SelectMany.
I don't understand three methods:
stream()
goDown().

How to convert these methods to .Net5?

Comment: Do not try to "translate" java to C# as literally as possible. Extract the _requirements_ from your existing java code. Then implement these in C# (and the C#-way). Don't think about "what's a FlatMap in C#?" - think about "how can I _do X_ in C#?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a brief glance at `Stream` in Java, it looks like that is basically their implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` and LINQ in C#. Essentially it is a toolset to do lazy evaluations over collections. Below is my best guess of what you are needing in C#

```cs
public class AdminNode : IEnumerable<Resource>
{
    private List<AdminNode> _children = new List<AdminNode>();
        
    public AdminNode(Resource resource)
    {
        Resource = resource;
    }
        
    public Resource Resource { get; }
        
    public IEnumerable<AdminNode> GoDown()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<AdminNode>();
        //this could be done recursively, but explicitly implementing with a stack
        //reduces the risk of a stack overflow exception with large trees
        stack.Push(this);
        while(stack.Any())
        {
            var next = stack.Pop();
            yield return next;
            foreach(var child in next._children)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
        
    public IEnumerator<Resource> GetEnumerator() { return GoDown().Select(x => x.Resource).GetEnumerator(); }
        
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GoDown().Select(x => x.Resource).GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

In this implementation, `GoDown()` should return an `IEnumerable<AdminNode>` of all the `AdminNode`s starting at the current `AdminNode` and all nodes below it.

If you enumerate an `AdminNode` it will enumerate over all resources starting at the current node, and then all resources of children below that node.

Comment: But AddResource methods I have to keep?

Comment: @hdoitc I thought you had the add resources methods figured out. I wasn't sure what the logic was that you were needing for adding resources, and the best I could do is just copy what you had in here.